Passing value to padding in compose BOX function does not effecting the output
I am new at Android Development. I have recently started Android Development course from Google Developer site.  i am making an app for a birthday wish but problem occurred that is i am passing value in padding in the calling of composable funtion but at first it shows an error when I put dp after value (eg. 8. dp) but then solve it buys just importing dp unit file but now when i am passing value to it don't show any error but also not applying any value to output. Following is the code of mainactivity.kt
package com.example.birthdayapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.birthdayapp.ui.theme.BirthdayappTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BirthdayappTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ){
                       GreetingImage(message = "Happy Birthday Brother!!!", form = "Prabhat Tripathi")

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greetingtext(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,form: String, message: String){
    Column {
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 100.sp,
            lineHeight = 116.sp
        )


        Text(
            text = form,
            fontSize = 40.sp
        )
    }
}
@Composable
fun GreetingImage(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,message: String, form: String){
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    Box {
        Image(
            painter = image, contentDescription = null

        )
        Greetingtext(form = form, message = message , modifier = Modifier.padding(start =10.dp, top = 5.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun HappyBirthdayWish() {
    BirthdayappTheme {
        GreetingImage( message ="Happy Birthday Brother " , form ="Prabhat Tripathi" )
    }
}

please help me i cant understand why is this happening. I have given my best to solve this problem i can't.

You have to apply the modifier parameter in Greetingtext, like this:
@Composable
fun Greetingtext(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,form: String, message: String){
    Column(modifier = modifier) { // <-- this
        Text(...)
        Text(...)
    }
}

The same goes for GreetingImage and any other composable, if you don't use the parameter, it won't do anything.
